# Unity - Game modes as state machine?

Tags: unity-game-engine, architecture, state-machine

I am making a quiz game in Unity and I've come across architectural problem.

I want the game to have few game modes, like standard, faster answer - more points, etc. Each of which will behave in its own specific way but some things will be very similar like answering questions, starting timer, etc.

Currently its structured based on [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YdERlPfwUb0&list=PLngpvtVrmJuPB94yNpIWhd_gmHXhBSr9k&index=55&t=1185s). There is a `QuizSystem` that holds reference to `QuestionDatabase`, `UIReferences`(buttons,score text, etc) and `GameSettings` (questions per game/per mode etc).

To start the game you need to call `QuizSystem.Start()` and it starts its current `GameMode` which derives from abstract `StateMachine` and is a monobehaviour (dont know if neccesary). I also have abstract `State` class from which different game states will derive from.  It has a constructor with `(GameMode owner)` as paramenter and 3 functions: `Start(), Tick(), End()`.

So, this way I can have `Standard` game mode which will instatiate lets say `StandardPreparationState`, which on end will call `StandardAnswerState` which will start the timer and wait for user input and again call `StandardPreparationState`. Cycle will repeat until questions per mode amount is reached and then delegate next action to `QuizSystem`.

The advantage of this approach is that every mode can behave in its own way like add additional steps in between but it kinda limits reusability. What I mean by that is if some `OtherMode` would have the same preparation functionality but different action afterwards, it wouldn't work beacause
`StandardPreparationState` would transition to `StandardAnswerState`.

I could add another parameter such as `(GameMode owner, State transitionTo)` to the `State` constructor but that somehow seems wrong I don't know why xD

What I want to know is how do you guys implement different game modes for your games? Do you make each mode as separate scene? Or maybe use States Machine pattern and have `Manager` class that takes care of starting/swaping modes?

I know that each game is different but are there maybe some common approaches for that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite open and opinion-based. However there are few "common" approaches, one of the most important is to make game "data-driven".

---

**What? Why? How?**

Imagine you are having space shooter, where you have your ship flying around and picking guns. Each time you add new gun, you will have to code its damage, kind of projectiles and how many of them you shoot, their color, in what pattern they spawn, speed, size, ...

Everytime you would want to add a new gun, you would need to enter the code and change it there, compile, ... Lot of work.

Instead people thought, "why don't we create simple class that holds all the parameters? We will make it editable from Unity, instatiate it in the project and we won't need to code that much."

This is when Unity brought [Scriptable object](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html)s.

---

**[Scriptable objects](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html)**

> A `ScriptableObject` is a data container that you can use to save large amounts of data, independent of class instances. One of the main use cases for `ScriptableObjects` is to reduce your Project’s memory usage by avoiding copies of values.

The idea is to create scriptable object for your mode and set up multiple kinds of modifiers that will the mode use. Folder structure might look like:

```
> ScriptableObjects
| |--> Modes
|    |-> NormalSO (instance)
|    |-> HardWithLotOfExpSO (instance)
|    |-> EasyWithLowerExpSO (instance)
> Script
  |--> ScriptableObjects
     |-> ModeSO
```

`ScriptableObject` is class that doesn't really have the logic inside, just creates "structure" for keeping data. Example of such class would be:

```
public class ModeSO : ScriptableObject
{
    public string modeName;

    public float scoreMultiplier;
    public int numberOfEnemiesMaxAlive;
    public int numberOfEnemiesTotal;

    public Vector3[] spawnPoints;
}
```

In the Unity itself you would then create instance of such objects. And what about interaction with other classes? Well, they would just work as:

- Game manager hold single instance of active mode
- Class that would be handling score (e.g. `player` / `scoreboard`) or `Enemy` would ask `GameManager` what is current multiplier for score
- `WorldSpawner` would ask `GameManager` how many enemies should he spawn, where, and when to spawn next ones
- At the beginning of the game you would be able to select difficulty by its name

Example of one of the classes (Scoreboard):

```
public class ScoreBoard: MonoBehavior
{
    GameManager manager;

    private float totalScore;

    OnEnemyDestroyed(float scoreForEnemy)
    {
        totalScore += scoreForEnemy * (manager?.activeMode?.modifier ?? 1);
    }
}
```

And the best is, whenever you will change some data, you will just modify the existing instance in the Unity. No need to go into code. No need to recompile whole game.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but that aproach kind of limits the possibilities of game modes. That way game modes will only differ by values which is too little for me. I would like being able to do different things based on current mode. I use ScriptableObject for questions until I will make some online database.

Comment: Bringing a little more to consider - cannot you put those "different things" also in another scriptable object? `BehaviorSO`? `WindowShakeSO`? `LayoutOfQuestionsSO`? Going around and around, `mode` can be a holder for several kinds of other `ScriptableObjects`.   It is not an answer for everything, but it might open ways you didn't know about. :)

Comment: yeah, I will see what I can come up with with that approach, thanks a lot and I wish you all the best!

Answer (score 0):

I think having different scenes for each game mode, especially if the modes are very similar save for a few settings, is unnecessary. I'd have to see more of your design to know how your game logic is being handled (is it all managed in one GameManager script? Or are there multiple scripts in the scene that take values from this manager script to handle game mechanics?)

One way I've handled different game modes before is to use a public int value in the GameManager that represents the different modes (i.e 1 = easy, 2 = medium, 3 = hard). I would then use a switch statement in any scripts whose behavior/values depend on this mode and reference that public int to determine game settings.

Game Manager:

```
public class GameManager: MonoBehavior
{
    public int gameMode = 0; //set to 1,2, or 3 by UI
    [...] //rest of game manager code
}
```

Example Behavior Script:

```
public class EnemySpawn: MonoBehavior
{
    public GameObject enemy;
    GameManager gm;
    
    private float spawnRate;
    Start()
    {
        switch(gm.gameMode)
        {
            case 1:
                 spawnRate = 15f;
                 break;
            case 2:
                 spawnRate = 10f;
                 break;
            case 3:
                 spawnRate = 5f;
                 break;
            default:
                 spawnRate = 10000f;
                 Debug.log("invalid mode");
                 break;
         }
    }
    Awake()
    {
        InvokeRepeating("SpawnEnemy", spawnRate, 0f);
    }
    [...] //rest of EnemySpawn code, including a SpawnEnemy() function.

}
```

This example would reference the GameManager's gameMode int to determine what speed to spawn enemies at, assuming there is a SpawnEnemy() function somewhere down in the code. I can't verify if this example is syntactically correct, but it's just to show one way to handle game modes.

Comment: This is example would be certainly working. The issue comes when you will keep it working for long time and once you will create 100th mode, you would have really long list to scroll in. Whenever you would add new variable for the mode, you must modify/add it in "each sector". Each script working with mode would have its own `switch`. To be clear, it is good answer for beginners. But once you know basics, you want to find better solution.

Comment: @Ryan thanks for the answer, I have updated my question. Regarding your answer, I would rly like to avoid switch statement for controlling different behaviour. With every additional mode the complexity and readabilty will be more and more difficult to manage.